NestJS socket.io app clustering. Connect to a specific cluster
I have a NestJS application for data streaming with socket.io. Calculations for data sent over a socket is quite resource-intensive so I decided to create multiple application instances by clustering it. Socket in each cluster emits events to a particular namespace.
Here is main.ts:
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import * as cluster from 'cluster';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter()
  );

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

  await app.listen(8081);
}

function main() {
  if (cluster.default.isPrimary) {
    console.log(`Master server started on ${process.pid}`);

    for (const namespace of ['namespace1', 'namespace2']) {
      cluster.default.fork({ namespace });
    }

    cluster.default.on('exit', (worker) => {
      console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died.`);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(`Cluster server started on ${process.pid}`);
    bootstrap();
  }
}

main();

And here is socket gateway:
import { WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({ namespace: process.env.namespace })
export class StreamGateway {
  @WebSocketServer() io: Server;

  constructor() {
    this.start();
  }

  async start() {
    // this.io.emit logic here
  }
}

The problem is that the client connects to a first available cluster, for example: when connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8081/namespace2, the connection is immediately closed with Error: Invalid namespace, since the client connects to the first available cluster with socket instance initialized with namespace1. If you try to reconnect immediately, the client will connect to cluster with different namespace, in this case correct namespace namespace2.
Solution that I came up with is to bind different port for each cluster and proxy requests with nginx to a specific port with given namespace. This method seems not really suitable when there is a lot of namespaces.
